# Getting error while using cmake command?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created rosbuild workspace (mywork) and a package (test) within it.

I was trying to build the package using cmake command

```
[rosbuild] Building package test
[rosbuild] Error from directory check: /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/check_same_directories.py  /home/admin-pc/mywork/test
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/check_same_directories.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise Exception
Exception
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:102 (message):
  [rosbuild] rospack found package "test" at "", but the current directory is
  "/home/admin-pc/mywork/test".  You should double-check your
  ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found in the correct
  precedence order.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:177 (_rosbuild_check_package_location)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72958/getting-error-while-using-cmake-command?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-08-14**:
With multiple hit and trial I found the solution that is to use command
source ~/mywork/setup.bash 
but I need to use this in every new terminal.
Please tell the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the only solution is to either add that line ("source ~/mywork/setup.bash") in your ~/.bashrc file, so that it gets executed for each new shell, or to manually source it in all terminals where you want to use your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [The Martin](https://answers.ros.org/users/5112/the-martin/) with karma: 52 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution depends on how you generated your rosbuild workspace. This [page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin) contains all the info you need. But I'll summarise below.

If you created your rosbuild workspace with **rosws** then add to your `~/.bashrc` the following line:

```
source $HOME/mywork/setup.bash
```

When going down this route make sure you called **rosws** *after* having sourced the setup.bash from your catkin devel directory (assuming you're mixing catkin and rosbuild). See the link above for more information.

Alternatively, if you want to set your workspace the "traditional" (pre-groovy) way, then append the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$HOME/mywork:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

This simply adds your rosbuild workspace to ROS's package path (which incidentally is what the error above was trying to tell you to do :P ).

---

Originally posted by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) with karma: 1114 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5